# What is a named cookie?

Tags: http, go, cookies

I am reading [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Cookie) about Go language and found:

> `Cookie` returns the named cookie provided in the request

When I try `req.Cookie("My-Cookie")` I receive `named cookie not present`

While when I `fmt.Println(req.Cookies())` I receive following string:

```
[My-Cookie=a783e7e4-c331-4802-6544-7374f5128882 Path=/svc Expires="Tue, 07 Feb 2068 16:05:53 GMT" Path=/svc HttpOnly=]
```

What is the named cookie then?

Comment: This just refers to the "name" parameter. The function returns the cookie with the given name. In your example there is one cookie with the name "My-Cookie".

Comment: Try printing the `Cookie.Name` directly. When you print `req.Cookies()`, it sanitizes the cookie name (replaces `\n` and `\r` with `-`)

Comment: Thank you @Marc. That was the issue

Comment: It also looks like you have a cookie inside a cookie, as there are no semicolons in the output, `Path` is listed twice, and `HttpOnly=` isn't a valid output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_VX_ZvlC_9A). It shows that what the OP posted works, so the bug is somewhere else. It also answers the question by showing what the named cookie is.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  r := &http.Request{
    Header: http.Header{
      "Cookie": []string{
        "My-Cookie=a783e7e4-c331-4802-6544-7374f5128882 Path=/svc Expires=Tue, 07 Feb 2068 16:05:53 GMT Path=/svc HttpOnly=",
      },
    },
  }

  fmt.Println(r.Cookies())

  c, err := r.Cookie("My-Cookie")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    return
  }

  // only cookie name and value are parsed
  fmt.Println("Name", c.Name)
  fmt.Println("Value", c.Value)

}
```